# How to connect Macbook Pro 2015 and 2 x Dell U2518D monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I bought 2 x  Dell U2518D monitors to use with my 2015 Macbook pro 13". This is a 2560x1440 1440p monitor.  All the forums said this could be done and that they were compatible, but I didn't check the dell driver page.  When I did check the page, there were no macbook drivers.

When I plugged the firs monitor in, nothing happened. It just went to sleep, said no HDMI input found.   This has never happened before with any other external monitor.

Do I need mac drivers?

I have the USB cable plugged into a USB port.

I have the HDMI cable plugged into the mDP.

I also bought the DELl 6000 universal docking station.  Not yet tried this, I thought I should be able to plug the monitor straight into the macbook.

I'm not really very techy, clearly. Please be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need Mac drivers for this monitor to function.

I think the problem is your cable. I would suggest using the cable that came with the monitor to connect the laptop and the display. That cable is a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable. If this is actually the cable you've used (and not HDMI as you mention), then try getting an alternative cable to test with.

All you need to do is to plug that cable into the laptop and the monitor, and you should get a picture. You might need to set the input on the monitor to Mini DisplayPort if you have disabled the auto function.

If that fails to work with a good cable, try rebooting the laptop with the cable plugged in. That should definitely not be necessary, but just to test out every option.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help.  The monitor was new out of the box, and I used the 2 cables it came with.  When I plugged in an old HDMI cable (that I had lying around) it did work. How many cables does it need?  Should it work with just the MDP - DP cable? Should it work with just the USB cable?   I will try rebooting with just one of them.  thanks .

Comment: It  only needs the MDP - DP cable. The USB cable is just for the USB hub, it doesn’t carry a “picture”.

Comment: Ah, ok, so if I want to plug in anything to the USB slots at the back of the monitor, I need to plug in the USB cable as well? So it is the HDMI or MDP plus the USB for the USB slots? thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you want to use the USB slots on the monitor, you need to plugin the USB cable. If you do not need to use them, you do not need to plug it in. If you want to show a picture on your display (you probably do), then you need to plug in either Mini DisplayPort, DisplayPort or HDMI.

Comment: Perfect! I think I get it now.  Many thanks.